# Any client library that can tell how long the request took?

Tags: scala, asynchttpclient

Is there any http-client library for scala that can tell how long time a request took?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the time library in Java.

```
var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// send request
var end = System.currentTimeMillis();
println("Round trip response time = " + (end-start) + " millis";
```

It seems that there is no need to have a http-client library to tell you about it.